# Is there any way to export a variable and change it after importing it?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using Webpack, and I have a `function.js` file with this code:

```
import { randomNum } from '../index.js';

export function getSlidePrev() {
  if (randomNum > 1) {
    randomNum -= 1;
    setBg(randomNum);
  }
}
```

And in my `main.js` file I have this:

```
function getRandomNum(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
export let randomNum = getRandomNum(firstSlideNumber, lastSlideNumber);

const slidePrev = document.querySelector('.slide-prev');
slidePrev.addEventListener('click', getSlidePrev);
```

I get this type of error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property randomNum of #<Object> which has only a getter
    at HTMLButtonElement.getSlidePrev
```

I tried to google, but I couldn't solve this issue. Someone says it's because of using Babel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An imported variable is a read-only, you cannot modify it in the file where it's imported. Here is what [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) says about it:

> The static `import` declaration is used to import read-only live bindings which are exported by another module. The imported bindings are called live bindings because they are updated by the module that exported the binding, but cannot be modified by the importing module.

You can turn `randomNum` into an object if you want to mutate it across different imports. For that change it in `index.js` to:

```
export const randomNum = {value : 1000};
```

And use it this way:

```
import { randomNum } from "../index.js";

export function getSlidePrev() {
  if (randomNum.value > 1) {
    randomNum.value -= 1;
    setBg(randomNum.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So what is the solution, how can i modify the value?

Comment: Why you don't define `randomNum` just above `getSlidePrev`? This way you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Because it has to stay in global js file, so i can use the same value in other functions. Or i can do otherwise?

Comment: When you change it in one function, the others should get the updated value or you want it just a global constant?

Comment: Yes, a global constant but i have to use it's value in other functions. But sometimes it has to be changed

Comment: If I understood you, my just edited answer should do what you want.

Comment: Glad it did @flopinski :)